# Travel Money & Expenses In Russia

Tags: budget, planning, russia, moscow, saint-petersburg

Can anyone recommend how much travel money I should be prepared to spend in Russia? I'll be spending 3 days in Moscow and 3 days in St Petersburg half board.

I will need money for lunch and souvenirs only (all other costs are covered).

I have looked at various calculators but many are out of date and I believe the Ruble rates change quite frequently.

Can someone advise?

Comment: Do you want an estimate of just lunch + souvenirs OR of the whole trip?

Comment: Lunch + souvenirs for the time I am there. As stated, all other costs have been covered. @Newton

Comment: I'm afraid without an idea of your standards and tastes (is a "souvenir" a subway token or a fox fur hat?), and the areas and venues you will be patronizing, estimates may vary considerably.

Comment: The rouble rates don't change much.

Answer (score 0):

The budget really depends on your preferences. For example, you easily can find some cafes in St. Petersburg center with prices around [$5 per dish](http://www.teremok.ru/address/), as well as [$10 per dish](http://v-teple.ru/menu/#dishes) or [$15 per dish](https://ginza.ru/spb/restaurant/terrassa). The same is about souvenirs - you can find a small shop or big shop with [completely different prices](http://souvenirboutique.com/contacts). Overall souvenir prices are from 5$ and higher.

Prices in Moscow, in general, are higher than in St. Petersburg, so you can multiply prices from above by `1.5`. After that, you can do your math.

About exchange rates - they are changing every day, but not that much. Usually the [`1 USD` is approximately `60 RUR` or slightly less.](https://ru.investing.com/currencies/usd-rub)